# When Convolving two signals why is there a "invalid data type" error?

Tags: matlab

I'am trying to find the convolution of two signals but it shows an error that I can't fix. each of the signals is graphically shown separately.
The error shown is:

```
    Error using conv2
    Invalid data type. First and second arguments must be numeric or logical.
    Error in conv (line 43)
    c = conv2(a(:),b(:),shape);
    Error in conv_m (line 5)
    y=conv(x,h);
    Error in thurja (line 7)
    [y,ny]=conv_m(x,nx,h,nh);
```

The code is :

```
    nx=0:20;
    x=(5+3.*cos(0.2.*pi.*nx)+4.*sin(0.6.*pi.*nx));
    nh=0:20;
    h=(141/100 - 141i/100).^nh.*(37262/19881 + 111623i/99405) + (141/100 + 141i/100).^nh.*(37262/19881 - 111623i/99405)+ (5000.*kroneckerDelta(sym(nh), sym(0))/19881) ;
    [y,ny]=conv_m(x,nx,h,nh);




    function [y,ny] = conv_m(x,nx,h,nh)
    nyb=nx(1)+nh(1);
    nye=nx(length(x))+nh(length(h));
    ny=[nyb:nye];
    y=conv(x,h);
    end
```

Comment: Obviously `kroneckerDelta(sym(nh), sym(0))` produces something that is not numeric. Convert to `double` using `double(kroneckerDelta(sym(nh), sym(0)))`, or create that data without using symbolic variables to begin with.

Comment: That bit of code *should* be equivalent to `(nh==0)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help